# Como usar Método Genérico com Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, genéricos, dapper

Tenho 2 métodos de um repositório genérico

```
public TEntity ObterPorId(int id)
{
    return Db.Set<TEntity>().Find();
}

public IEnumerable<TEntity> ObterTodos()
{
    return Db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

porém quero utilizar o Dapper, pra obter um pouquinho mais de performance, pois o método `ObterTodos` do Entity está demorando muito pra trazer os dados.

Como posso fazer isso utilizando o Dapper?

Comment: Talvez o link te ajude a seguir um caminho... http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/12/creating-data-repository-using-dapper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja este artigo da Poliana Dias, elá está desenvolvendo um projeto no GitHub com Dapper, lá tem um exemplo de um metodo generico.

O projeto está bem no começo, fácil de entender e acompanhar..

https://polianadias.wordpress.com/2016/05/19/implementando-dapper-e-dapper-extensions-no-asp-net-mvc-usando-ddd-solid-di-ioc-crosscutting-e-selfvalidation/

OU diretamente no GH
https://github.com/polianadias/arquitetura-modelo